# is it possible to disable all the tab on same page on button click using jquery?

Tags: jquery

how to disable tabs on button click using button id in jquery?
     In following PHP page there are four tabs declared in li tag which i creatd using bootstarp.

```
<form class="form span11">
    <div class="tabbable" id="tab">
        <div class="">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a href="#comments" data-toggle="tab">Comments</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Activities</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#locations" data-toggle="tab">Locations</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#pohistory" data-toggle="tab">PO History</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="comments">
                <?php include "views/projects/comments.php"; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane " id="locations">
                <?php include "partners_locations.php"; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane " id="pohistory">
                <?php include "pohistory.php"; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<button id="set" type="button">submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#set").click(function () {
    $( "#tab" ).tabs({ disabled: true });
});
```